# Synchronization, When to or not to use?

Tags: java, synchronized

I have started learning concurrency and threads in Java. I know the basics of synchronized (i.e. what it does). Conceptually I understand that it provides mutually exclusive access to a shared resource with multiple threads in Java. But when faced with an example like the one below I am confused about whether it is a good idea to have it synchronized. I know that critical sections of the code should be synchronized and this keyword should not be overused or it effects the performance.

```
public static synchronized List<AClass> sortA(AClass[] aArray) 
{
    List<AClass> aObj = getList(aArray);

    Collections.sort(aObj, new AComparator());

    return aObj;
}

public static synchronized List<AClass> getList(AClass[] anArray) 
{
    //It converts an array to a list and returns
}
```

Comment: No synchronization needed because your methods seem stateless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming each thread passes **a different array** then no synchronization is needed, because the rest of the variables are local.

If instead you fire off a few threads all calling `sortA` and passing a reference to the same array, **you'd be in trouble** without `synchronized`, because they would interfere with eachother.

Beware, that it would seem from the example that the `getList` method returns a new `List` from an array, such that even if the threads pass the same array, you get different `List` objects. This is misleading. For example, using `Arrays.asList` creates a `List` backed by the given array, but the javadoc clearly states that `Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.` so be careful about this.

Answer (score 7):

Synchronization is usually needed when you are sharing data between multiple invocations and there is a possibility that the data would be modified resulting in inconsistency. If the data is read-only then you dont need to synchronize.

In the code snippet above, there is no data that is being shared. The methods work on the input provided and return the output. If multiple threads invoke one of your method, each invocation will have its own input and output. Hence, there is no chance of in-consistency anywhere. So, your methods in the above snippet need not be synchornized.

Synchronisation, if unnecessarily used, would sure degrade the performance due to the overheads involved and hence should be cautiously used only when required.

Comment: How do you know that no data is being shared? The threads may pass the same array to the `sortA` method.

Comment: Quite a possibility! Well, in that case you sure would need to synchornize. The point is that the users of the code should know whether your code is thread safe or not. As a developer, you know whether your code should be thread safe or not. If not then you need to document it for the users so that they may explicitly synchronize in interesting scenarios. You need not go about synchronizing everything in your code.

Comment: Synchronizing a static method in the snippet above for the functionality it provides is not correct. The users should guard against the scenario you mentioned externally wherever required.

Answer (score 2):

Your static methods don't depend on any shared state, so need not be synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule defined like when to use synchronized and when not, when you are sure that your code will not be accessed by concurrent threads then you can avoid using synchronised.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization as you have correctly figured has an impact on the throughput of your application, and can also lead to starving thread.

All get basically should be non blocking as Collections under concurrency package have implemented.

As in your example all calling thread will pass there own copy of array, `getList` doesn't need to be synchronized so is `sortA` method as all other variables are local.

Local variables live on stack and every thread has its own stack so other threads cannot interfere with it.

You need synchronization when you change the state of the Object that other threads should see in an consistent state, if your calls don't change the state of the object you don't need synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `synchronized` on single threaded code. i.e. where there is no chance an object will be accessed by multiple threads.

This may appear obvious but ~99% of StringBuffer used in the JDK can only be used by one thread can be replaced with a StringBuilder (which is not synchronized)