# Where do i have to use synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have done some research and could not find a solution to this problem.

From this topic [Synchronization, When to or not to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581366/synchronization-when-to-or-not-to-use) i understand i could use `synchronized`, but doing so doesn't solve the problem.

The case is that i have a method in which a `Thread` is used to create an `ArrayList`. In that same `Thread` another `method` is called after a `BufferedReader` has finished reading a file and the lines are being added to the first List.

In the second method the first list is being used to create the second List. When all that is done, the first method uses the second list.

This is somewhat the code i use, if there is something not clear please ask and i will try to provide the info needed.

```
public synchronized void theBaseList() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @override
        public void run() {
          try(
              while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  firstList.add(line):
              }
          }
          nextMethod();
          currentObject = (Object[]) secondList.get(0); // throws an exception
          }
      }
  };
  t.start();
```

---

```
public synchronized void nextMethod() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        double objectListSize = calculateObjectListLength(firstList.size());
        @override
        public void run() {
          try {
              // create Objects
              secondList.add(objects);
            }
         }
      };
      t1.start();
}
```

When i use a `Thread` in `nextMethod()` to create a new `list` of Objects from the items in the first list, i get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` saying

> Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

I avoided this by not using a `Thread` in the second method and all works fine.

If i do use 2 `Threads` and make both methods `synchronized`, it still throws the exception.

Is it possible or should i just settle by not using a `Thread` in the second method? I thought `synchronized` was for dealing with this sort of problems. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean 'when running methods in separate threads'?

Comment: @EJP yes, one method is getting called from the thread in the first method.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a reason to use separate threads here. The operations are serial. `t1` depends on `t` to finish filling the first list and `t` depends on `t1` to add to the second list.

Comment: @Radiodef i did it like that because there was also a progressbar in there and i couldn't get it to update progress without using a thread.

Comment: @Radiodef well because it is serial, i don't understand why it gives problems.

Comment: So if you mean 'when running methods in separate threads' why does your title say 'when running threads in separate methods'? It's meaningless.

Comment: @EJP i have changed the title, maybe it captures the question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your methods are defined in a class named Sample and you've created an instance mySample. This appears to be what your code is doing:

```
main thread calls mySample.theBaseList() and synchronizes by locking on mySample.
  theBaseList() defines thread1 and starts it.
  theBaseList() exits scope, thus unlocking on mySample.

thread1 reads in the lines of a file and adds them to list1 (these operations are not synchronized)
thread1 calls mySample.nextMethod()
mySample.nextMethod() synchronizes by locking on mySample
    nextMethod() defines thread2 and starts it.
    nextMethod() exits scope, thus unlocking on mySample.

* thread2 sets up list2 (these operations are not synchronized)
* thread1, having returned from nextMethod() reads from list2 (these operations are not synchronized)
```

The last two operations are the cause of your race condition.

In your case, using synchronized methods is perhaps too coarse grained. A better option may be to synchronize on the object on which both threads operate, secondList.

```
nextMethod();
synchronized(secondList) {
    currentObject = (Object[]) secondList.get(0); // should no longer throw an exception
}

synchronized(secondList) {
    // create Objects
    secondList.add(objects);
}
```

EDIT:

```
synchronized(secondList) {
    nextMethod();
    secondList.wait();
    currentObject = (Object[]) secondList.get(0); // should no longer throw an exception
}

synchronized(secondList) {
    // create Objects
    secondList.add(objects);
    secondList.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know `synchronized` could be used outside or in this case inside of a method declaration.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. `t` can still acquire the lock while the list is empty.

Comment: Ah, you're right @Radiodef. t can either wait until the second list has been populated or t2 shouldn't be created in the first place.

Comment: @chiaboy i will try this in the morning to see if it will work.

Comment: Edit to the code snippet should fix the problem highlighted by @Radiodef. Assuming the use case really does require 2 additional threads.