# Does Static Methods give bad results if two threads having own objects accessing same?

Tags: java, multithreading, static-methods

Does Static non synchronized Methods give bad results if two threads accessing same?

```
public class MySubjectUtils {
   public static MyResponseClass createMyResponseClass(MyParameter record) {
   if (record == null) {
     return null;
   }
   MyResponseClass mRes = new MyResponseClass()
   mRes.setName(record.getName());
   mRes.setAddress(record.getAddress());   
   return mRes;
}
```

If two or more threads trying to access MySubjectUtils.createMyResponseClass(record); Will both gives results of their own or will they mix it up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronization, When to or not to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581366/synchronization-when-to-or-not-to-use)

Comment: You can't tell from this code. If both threads use the same `record` object, then it depends on whether the way that the data in record was written, was properly synchronized wrt the two threads. If it was, and your getters only read data, then you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since MySubjectUtils.createMyResponseClass(record) method creates a new instance of MyResponseClass(), each call to this method will create a new object. So each thread will receive its own object.
2. If your both threads are passing the same record object, actual contents of their MyResponseClass instances will be the same.
3. If threads are passing different instances of record object, their MyResponseClass instances will have different contents.

Comment: Situation: it is A web service which further call a web service and from that further service response we create new response. Now A web service is hit by multiple users and parameters are sent to further service and for each user we get separate response which needs to populate in MyResponseObject and for that i am using STATICMETHOD.methodname as i want all utility methods at one place.

Answer (score 0):

**If** the object `record` refers to is immutable, you don't need any synchronization in that method, since that's the only potentially-shared resource that the method references. Everything else is local to the method.

But if the object `record` refers to **isn't** immutable *and* it may be used across threads, it could be modified by another thread between this method's calls to `getName` and `getAddress`, leading to an invalid response.

So the answer is: You may or may not need synchronization, and if you do, how you implement it will vary. In both cases, it depends on the definition of the `MyParameter` class and how the object `result` references is used by the calling code.

Comment: See it is A web service which further call a web service and from that further service response we create new response. Now A web service is hit by multiple users and parameters are sent to further service and for each user we get separate response which needs to populate in MyResponseClass and for that i am using STATICMETHOD.methodname as i want all utility methods at one place.

Comment: @fatherazrael: If you know that the calling code is the only code with a reference to that result object and the calling code doesn't share that object with another thread, you don't need synchronization. For instance: If `result` is a local within the calling code and isn't used with other methods that share it with other threads, you're fine.

Answer (score -1):

It will not have any performance issues, and since the method is not accessing some shared resources, the threads will get their own unique result.

Comment: They could well be accessing a shared resource: `record`, the object referenced by the parameter.

Comment: That's true, but its irrelevant for this case. The MyResponseClass object will still be unique to the different threads, and since Strings are immutable in Java, the name and address won't change if the record is changed.

Comment: It's relevant to whether this needs synchronization: Without it, the object `record` refers to can be changed between calls to `getName` and `getAddress`, making the result incorrect. Unless that object is immutable (the question doesn't say), the method would need synchronization if accessed by multple threads.